# How do I embed an external HTML from a web app into a shadow DOM in another web app?

Tags: html, shadow-dom, native-web-component

Here's how I've done it. I've created 2 web apps.

1. Web app 1 hosted on localhost 8081 using a Web Component to embed the 2nd app in a shadow DOM.
2. Web app 2 hosted on localhost 4200 serving a simple Angular starter app.

Here's how I tried embedding Web app 2 within Web app 1's shadow DOM.

```
const url = 'http://localhost:4200'; // angular starter app
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(html -> {
    const shadow = this.container.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}); // container is just a div
    shadow.innerHTML = html;
});
```

I ended up with the following DOM structure.

[image]

As it shows, the resources from Web app 2 are being resolved to Web app 1's base URL localhost 8081 which will fail to load as these resources are located at localhost 4200.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this even a good use case for using shadow DOM instead of using the old-fashioned iframe way for embedding another web app?

I've read some articles like [this](https://medium.com/bbc-design-engineering/goodbye-iframes-6c84a651e137) implying shadow DOM to be the right tool (or a substitute for iframe) for embedding external contents though doesn't really say if the contents need to be free from JavaScript or other external resources to make it work.

Comment: You are treating a whole (Angular generated) ``document`` (with ``<meta>`` tags and the lot) as HTML.. that (most likely) will not work; shadowDOM is not the same as an IFrame (which can take ``document`` content) I don't know how those ``<meta>`` and ``<base>`` tags behave... but ``<script>`` will **never** run when injected with ``innerHTML``. So yes, an IFRAME is probably the solution you want

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman, thanks. Is there any other way to "inject" JavaScript into a shadow DOM? And if it does work, would it be as isolated as the styles and elements in the shadow DOM?

Comment: @supertonsky  I am looking for something similar, did you find a solution ?